# Why i am getting an error Factory method 'halLinkDisocoverer' threw exception in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

Hi i am new at springboot, i trying to create RESTful API with it, it's already work when i create controller with it, but when i trying to add this line at pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

it give me error when i trying to run the application with `java -jar target/gs-accessing-mongodb-data-rest-0.1.0.jar`

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'halLinkDisocoverer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/mediatype/hal/HalMediaTypeConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer]: Factory method 'halLinkDisocoverer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.KotakKantorMovieDbApplication.main(KotakKantorMovieDbApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[KotakKantorMovieDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[KotakKantorMovieDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[KotakKantorMovieDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[KotakKantorMovieDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer]: Factory method 'halLinkDisocoverer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           ... 27 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/PathNotFoundException
>           at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration.halLinkDisocoverer(HalMediaTypeConfiguration.java:65) ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e51c0b.CGLIB$halLinkDisocoverer$2() ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e51c0b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bb4bacfd.invoke() ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalMediaTypeConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e51c0b.halLinkDisocoverer() ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>           ... 28 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException
>           at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[KotakKantorMovieDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]

i haven't do anything with it, when i just add that dependency, my apps give me this error. Here is my complete pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.movie.db</groupId>
    <artifactId>KotakKantorMovieDB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>KotakKantorMovieDB</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is my controller :

```
package com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.controllers;

import com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.models.Customer;
import com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.repository.CustomerRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class CustomerController {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerRepository repository;

  @GetMapping("/customer")
  public Customer findCustomer() {
    return repository.findByFirstName("cactuspot");
  }

  @PostMapping("/addcustomer")
  public Customer addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer newCustomer ) {
    return repository.save(newCustomer);
  }

}
```

here is my model :

```
package com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.models;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Customer {
    @Id
    public String id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

and here is my repository :

```
package com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.repository;

import java.util.List;

import com.movie.db.KotakKantorMovieDB.models.Customer;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

what did i missed here? i is there some dependency that i shouldn't use whtn i add `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726282/jsonpath-noclassdeffounderror-or-an-alternative-to-jsonpath-in-java

Comment: i already add json-path dependency in my pom.xml, u can see it in my pom.xml before

Comment: The dependency is on test scope. It means it's only available during test compilation/execution. Remove the scope tag to use "compile" scope

Comment: @danieljohngomez tried it, and it doesn't fixed the error, still have the same error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i trying to delete :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

this dependency, and it solved the error, i dunno why this dependency cause the error, and i dunno why this dependency is needed, i run my apps and it just work fine without this dependency. maybe there is something to do with HATEOAS. If somebody can explain it to me, i will accept it as an answer

Comment: It worked for me aswell, thanks, I'd also like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175889/error-creating-bean-with-name-hallinkdisocoverer-defined-in-class-path-resourc) but not working for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Those who are still facing this issue with the test scope remove the test scope. Add this dependency in pom.xml it will work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The weird thing that it is in them tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/ @Adding a JSON Library

Answer (score 1):

I came from udemy.
I got the same error and the author suggested to replace

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
<version>3.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error is in scope tag of this dependency of test

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove the scope tag and add like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then it worked for me without any other changes

Thanks