# Migrating from java 8 to 11 - jaxws-rt

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-8

I´ve migrated from Java 8 to Java 11 and I´ve found that some Java EE libraries are deprecated and I have to use some third party dependencies instead.

So I´ve added these dependencies to maven pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- JAXWS for Java 11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>${com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>${com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where the version in the variable is `2.3.2`.
But when I start the build, there are tons of warnings like this

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:459)    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252)
>     at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)    at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor80.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:233)
>     ... 112 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   C:\Users\USER.m2\repository\org\glassfish\ha\ha-api\3.1.12\javax.inject.jar
>     at
>   java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198)
>     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1763)    at
>   java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1225)     at
>   java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:727)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
>     at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:247)     at
>   java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)  at
>   java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:346)  ... 116
>   common frames omitted

The jaxws-rt plugin should load that ha rependence, or not?

In the following exceptions, there are missing files in the ha-API package and another missing file in those jaxws-rt dependencies like:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl

If i import that hp api dependency, the problem does not dissapear. I have no clue what to do, is there anyone who could help?

EDIT:

The folder have these files inside
[image]

EDIT2:

After I excluded inject dependency from both QueryDsl artifacts (apt and jpa) I am unable to install. Here is error I am getting:

There is no other javax.inject in dependency tree after exluding that dependency from both querydsl artifacts.

The Error occures when building "Q" objects (QEntities used in the querydsl queries)

```
[ERROR] execute error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Inject
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report (FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.mysema.maven.apt.AbstractProcessorMojo.execute (AbstractProcessorMojo.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Inject
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions (JavacTaskImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Inject
    at com.querydsl.codegen.AbstractModule.createInstance (AbstractModule.java:116)
    at com.querydsl.codegen.AbstractModule.get (AbstractModule.java:86)
    at com.querydsl.apt.DefaultConfiguration.getTypeMappings (DefaultConfiguration.java:410)
    at com.querydsl.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor.process (AbstractQuerydslProcessor.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1334)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:936)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions (JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Inject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.querydsl.codegen.AbstractModule.createInstance (AbstractModule.java:116)
    at com.querydsl.codegen.AbstractModule.get (AbstractModule.java:86)
    at com.querydsl.apt.DefaultConfiguration.getTypeMappings (DefaultConfiguration.java:410)
    at com.querydsl.apt.AbstractQuerydslProcessor.process (AbstractQuerydslProcessor.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1334)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:936)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0 (JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions (JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

EDIT 3: After excluding javax.inject from querydsl dependency and adding it as normal dependency, it compiles, but shows these warnings at the start (all NoSuchFileException:

```
...
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.1/javax.annotation-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.1/javax.jws-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.1/jaxb-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
ailed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.1/jaxws-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.1/javax.xml.soap-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.1/FastInfoset.jar] from classloader hierarchy
...
```

(and many others from com/sun/**)

and then many from glassfish like - still NoSuchFileException

```
...
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.9/asm-all-repackaged.jar] from classloader hierarchy
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.9/hk2-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/USER/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.9/osgi-resource-locator.jar] from classloader hierarchy
...
```

Comment: Seemingly the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726282/jsonpath-noclassdeffounderror-or-an-alternative-to-jsonpath-in-java

Comment: Well, as i mentioned in the topic, even if I add the libraries from that FileNotFoundexception (so glassfish ha-api), the exception occures.If that new dependency have some dependencies, It should download these dependencies automatically, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, it is.
The question is why the path to the jar is incorrect. The log contains 'NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\ha\ha-api\3.1.12\javax.inject.jar',
while expected reference should be 'C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\ha\ha-api\3.1.12\ha-api-3.1.12.jar'

Comment: @edwgiz I´ve added the screenshot of folder that should contain the files and you are right, there are wrong names of the files. Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Are you using [javax.inject](http://javax-inject.github.io/javax-inject/) API in your project?

Comment: @Boris I doubt it, there is no dependency in pom.xml and there are no other dependencies managed outside maven.

Comment: Can you run a maven goal `dependency:tree`? Are there any `javax.inject` dependencies?

Comment: @Boris Oh, you were right. The com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa package has the javax.inject:javax.inject dependency bundled. Is this the cause of my problem? And if its can you please tell me how to solve it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem was with Tomcat Servler Jar scanning**

Problem was solved by adding the bean holding tomcat configuration disabling scanning manifest

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory();
}

static class CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory extends TomcatServletWebServerFactory {

    @Override
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
    }
}
```

The bean can be non-static too, but if you are using `management.server.port` property (for Spring Boot Admin app etc.), you have to make that Tomcat configuration static.

The other solution can be done by adding this to application property file in Spring Boot application

```
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar
```

**But this solution will break JSP or JSTL support!** So if you have to use these technologies in your project, you got to add the Bean above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

jaxws-rt 2.3.1 depends on javax servlet implmementation deprecated in java 11.

if you have the code:

- Move to jaxws-rt 4.0.0 , this one depends on jakarta servlet
  implementation supported in java 11.  Modify your pom with this rt
  version 4.0.0.
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/4.0.0
- modify your declare imports with javax move to jakarta to be ready for java11.

if you dont have compilation time error problably you dont have in execution time to.

Comment: Don't do this without careful consideration. jaxws-rt 4.0 is Jakarta EE 9+ (switched to the `jakarta.*` package naming), and OP still seems to use Jakarta EE 8 or lower (`javax.*` package naming).