# Unable to import taglibs using JSTL on Java 11 Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jstl, taglib, jstl-functions

First of all I would like to say I found threads on SO talking about this problem (even 2020 comments) and none of them helped me fix this problem.

I am migrating project from java 8 (Oracle SDK) to java 11 (AdoptOpenJDK, last version of java 11).

I am using maven, spring boot and jstl (beside of other dependencies that does not affect this problem).

The IDE is Intellij IDEA

Spring Boot release is 2.2.4, jstl is imported like this (in pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The application is clean installed by maven pretty easily, when I run the app, I get a tomcat error -

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

When I look into a console, I find this error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/error/error-debug.jsp (line: [1], column: [1]) The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:380)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:481)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.__compile(Compiler.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:41002)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:40001)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterNestedErrorDispatch(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$SessionCommittingRequestDispatcher.forward(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Problem is tomcat (or JSTL) want to run this code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<%-- Spring --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

When I comment out the first 3 rows (so just Spring taglib is present), I get the same error (just with other URI pointing to springframework.org...). When I remove all these lines, I get an error telling me I use prefix c: which is not present, what is expected behav.

What is pretty weird is a fact I can "ctrl + click" into the "uri" xml param pointing me to the right direction, in case of first row I am pointed to *...m2/repository/org/glassfish/web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.6/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.6.jar!/META-INF/c.tld* which I assume is correct path

**EDIT:**

The problem disappears with commenting out the tomcat configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

    static class CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory extends TomcatServletWebServerFactory {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Configuration is solving my problem mentioned here:
[Migrating from java 8 to 11 - jaxws-rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395722/migrating-from-java-8-to-11-jaxws-rt)

Is there any possibility to solve both problems at once? It is pretty annoying to have tons of warnings while starting application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutionn I find and seems to be working is maybe not that pretty as I would like, so if there is anyone who knows a better solution, feel free to post yours solution.

I enhanced TomcatConfiguration from my other thread mentioned at the end of this thread by explicitly selecting the jars that caused the warnings tomcat should not scan.

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

    static class CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory extends TomcatServletWebServerFactory {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            Set<String> pattern = new LinkedHashSet<>();

            pattern.add("jaxb*.jar");
            pattern.add("jaxws*.jar");
            pattern.add("ha-api*.jar");

            StandardJarScanFilter filter = new StandardJarScanFilter();
            filter.setTldSkip(StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(pattern));

            ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setJarScanFilter(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution seems to be working (the Tomcat does not scan the packages causing problems but can scan packages with jstl support to correctly compile the taglibs)